# mongoose Update object without "drop"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i have there a problem with mongoose & update documents.

when i upate a object in a collection then it "clear/drop" the object, and fill it with the to update object. But i need to "add/merge" the objects.

As Example:

```js
Model.update({name: "hello"}, {
  name: "hello",
  datum: {
    updated: Date.now(),
    //added: Date.now()
  }
}, function(err, data){
  
  console.log(err, data);
  
});
```

This replace my "datum" object with on field: "updated.
The "added" filed is deleted. WHY ?
How can i update the nested "datum" object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `$set` operator. If you don't specify it, the first document that matches your query document (1st parameter) will get replaced by your update document (2nd parameter) :

```
Model.update({name: "hello"}, {
  $set: {
      "datum.updated": Date.now()
  }
}, function(err, data){
    console.log(err, data);
});
```