# mongoose Update object without “drop”

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, save

I have this model:

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
email:{
  type: String,
  unique: true, 
  required: true
},
password:{
  type: String,
  required: true
},
obj1: { 
  type: Object, 
  unique : true,
  dropDups : true
}
});
```

Then the initial data on register is:

```
   new User({
              email:email,
              password:password,
              obj1:
                {
                  address: '0x1232424...', 
                  amount: 1578, 
                  time: Date.now()  
                }
            })
```

And when I try to update data I can't change only a data inside the object, but it changes all the object data..
So If I want to change the amount only, then the obj1.address and obj1.time is deleted..

```
     await User.update (
        { email: user[0].email }, 
        {
          obj1:{
             amount: 2245, 
           }
        } 
      )
```

Found this one [mongoose Update object without "drop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36229712/mongoose-update-object-without-drop) that says to add $set operator, but it still drops data..

How can I change only one data inside the object in mongoDB with mongoose without deleting other data in the same object..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update you're using is a replace style update where the entire document is replaced with a new one.  If you want to only update a single field, use the `$set` operator:

```
.update({email: user[0].email},{$set:{"obj1.amount":2245}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **spread operator**  to update only the field you want and let the other fields stay as they are .so try the following code:

```
await User.update ( { email: user[0].email }, { obj1:{...obj1, amount: 2245, } } );
```

Comment: Hi, just tried this, the amount field was changed but the other two fields ( address and time ) got deleted again..

Comment: You can put them in the curly braces with the same values